# Lithium battery - understanding health, current capacity and expected lifespan

Tags: batteries, lithium

**Short Question :**

I've got a Tadiran TL-5104 battery - data sheet [HERE](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/TADIRAN%20PDFs/TL-5104.pdf)

I've tested the battery with a multimeter at room temp (c. 20 °C) and got the following readings : 3.57 V, 0.85 mA

From the above data sheet and test results is it possible to know :

- a) the condition of the battery?
- b) how much charge % the battery still has in it?

Further :

- c) even if the battery was healthy and had say 75% of its initial charge, if the battery is c. 10 years old, could its performance under normal circumstances "drop off a cliff" and fail? (eg. if the battery is c. 10 years old and is healthy, had 75% charge, is it reasonable to expect its lifespan to be at least another 10 years, or is it reasonable to expect it to fail without warning?

**Background :**

The battery is integrated into a PCB of a small industrial processor and is used for memory retention. The battery is not charged by the PCB and once it is dead the battery needs to be replaced, the operating system and config needs to be reinstalled on the processor.

I have a lot of these PCBs and before going to the effort to replace all the batteries, I would like to get a better understanding of their performance.

Comment: How were you measuring current?

Comment: @vir by applying the probes of the multi meter to the terminals of the battery (whilst the battery was still soldered to the PCB)

Comment: @user27511 - Hi, I've just tided your question a little, to help readability. I think there was a missing word and that you meant: "[...] is it reasonable to expect it to fail without [warning]?" so I added that word. If you meant another word after "without" then please edit to replace my guess of "warning". (P.S. FYI this is a lithium primary cell, not a  rechargeable lithium-ion cell, so I fixed the tags too.)

Comment: _"by applying the probes of the multi meter to the terminals of the battery"_- it's still not clear how you got 3.57V and 0.85mA. Did you apply a load that drew 0.85mA at 3.57V, or set the multimeter to current and short out the battery with it.

Comment: @BruceAbbott apologies, Im not sure (I'm a little new to these things), so Ill explain in layman terms, the battery was soldered to the PCB. The PCB / processor was not connected to the PSU. I took my multi meter put it in V mode, and put one probe on one end of the cell and the the other probe on the other end of the cell and took the reading. I did the same to read the amps but with the multi meter set to ma mode. I noticed whilst reading the ma the reading kept decreasing.

Comment: If you look at the datasheet you’ll see the voltage is near flat until end of life where it drops off a cliff. So measuring voltage will only tell you if it is good or bad. Depending on the load, I’ve observed lifetimes in the range of 25years. If in doubt, replace the battery. With some care you can parallel another battery temporarily whilst you replace the battery and not lose the backed up data. Your method of testing the current is killing the batteries - you do not test current the way you described. voltage, yes.

Comment: Shorting out a battery with your multimeter is a great way to kill the battery or your multimeter's current mode function.  Sounds like you got lucky, but don't try that again.

Comment: @Kartman how should i measure the current, using a resistor ?